# email shows @ as %40

Tags: php, yii

I am working on Yii and I need to send a confirmation email one sign up. The content shows the email as abc%40@example.com

the email is directly called from the database and added to the mail function

I am not sure how this can be fixed

```
$activation_url = $this->createAbsoluteUrl('/user/activation/activation',array("activkey" => $registerform->activkey, "email" => $registerform->email));
```

the above code is the sample

Any help is appreciated

**Apologies** 
the result is shown like this  abc%40example.com and not abc%40@example.com

Comment: This is character encoding. Decode email and keep on coding.

Comment: `abc%40@...` would correspond to `abc@@...`. php won't magically add a new char to a string like that. something elsewhere in your code must be doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$activation_url = $this->createAbsoluteUrl('/user/activation/activation',array("activkey" => $registerform->activkey, "email" => urldecode($registerform->email)));
```